# Mantle Brackets on Brick Fireplace Wall

Tags: mounting, brackets, fixings

I have a fireplace wall that is 8’8” wide. The brick stops at 62 1/2” high and then there is a small stud wall above it with 3/4” pine penny gap that’s flush with the face of the brick, all the way up to the ceiling.

[image]
[image]

I have a heart pine mantle that’s roughly 4x6 and 8’8” long. The mantle weighs 50 lbs.

[image]

I want to use 2 custom made 1/4” thick iron L brackets to mount the mantle. The brackets will be 5” wide and can be made to any height I want. So the mounting holes can be any size and spaced as far apart or as close as I want. My intention is to have two mounting holes near the top of the bracket and two at the bottom.  The picture of the bracket below shows one bottom mounting hole, but it can be made with two. They will be made like this…

[image]
[image]

I want to mount the mantle where it will directly cover the transition from brick to shiplap. So the top of the bracket would ideally sit somewhere around the bottom of the top row of brick, give or take.

The bricks are the “three-hole” type, so they each have three voids near the middle. Here’s a pic of the bottom of one the bricks sitting on the lintel above the firebox…

[image]

I don’t know how to determine if the mortar has substantial enough compressive strength to hold the weight safely. So I feel like the brick is the better option if at all possible.

That said, there’s right at one inch of “meat” from the face of the brick to the interior core holes. Can I use a Tapcon as long as there is 1” of embedded depth, even if the tip or some length of the Tapcon ends up inside the void of the core hole? Will it still tighten fully? If not, how should these be mounted and what type of anchor should be used?

I’m looking at the Toggler Alligator anchors, probably the AF8 size with a 1/4” screw or bolt. They are one of the few that actually mention the anchor being suitable for going into a cavity in the brick, such as one of the center holes in a three hole brick. It’s a plastic anchor. Football accounts appears to be strong enough for what I need. Assuming I choose an appropriate screw or bolt. Does anyone have any experience with these? Check out pic 3b. toggler.com/pdfs/ALLIGATOR%C2%AE-Solid-Wall-Anchors.pdf

I would warmly welcome any potential solutions, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TBH, I doubt you benefit much from two holes on the bottom—those fasteners would only be of use in shear, since you have no tension there.  Is that last pic of the top of the fireplace opening?  What kind of structure do you have behind the brick, and shiplap?  I assume that's some kind of steel angle that the bricks are sitting on at the top of the fireplace opening?

Comment: @Huesmann  The last pic is in fact the top of the fireplace opening. I took that pic of the lintel to show that the bricks have three core holes. I wasn’t sure about drilling into these. What if you drill into one of the core holes? Is the depth along the outer edge enough? I’m not certain of the structure behind the fireplace wall. It appears to be solid as it’s the same 8’8” width outside. I think the left side above the “cubby” is a single wythe of brick in front of some sort of CMU block that makes up the meat of the wall. As for above the fireplace opening, I’m not sure.

Comment: Do you want the top of the mantle to be flush with the top of the bricks?

Comment: @Huesmann No, my intention is for the mantle to cover the transition between brick and shiplap…not necessarily dead center but covering the transition entirely.

Comment: Seems to me you could pry off the bottom shiplap board and see what's behind it...

Comment: I built the half wall with the shiplap. The brick originally stopped at 62 1/2”. I had just over 3 inches of depth from the wall to the face of the brick above the top row. I accounted for a layer of durock and 3/4” shiplap, and then ripped studs to make the shiplap flush with the face of the brick. What I really need to know is what kind of brick anchor can be used, knowing that I only have 1” of brick from the face to the interior core hole? Would a tapcon work assuming the end will be in the void of the core hole, since I still technically get 1” of embedment? Would a sleeve anchor work?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't anchor *through* the interior hole?

Comment: By “through,” do you mean drilling and anchoring all the way into the brick on the other side of the core hole, and end up with 1” of embedment in front of the core hole and up to another 1” behind the core hole? I had thought about that initially, but wasn’t sure if the mid section of the anchor and/or screw not being embedded was an issue or not. Not sure how something like a sleeve anchor would react.

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean.

Comment: I’m looking at the Toggler Alligator anchors, probably the AF8 size with a 1/4” screw or bolt. They are one of the few that actually mention the anchor being suitable for going into a cavity in the brick, such as one of the center holes in a three hole brick. It’s a plastic anchor. Football accounts appears to be strong enough for what I need. Assuming I choose an appropriate screw or bolt. Does anyone have any experience with these? Check out pic 3b. https://toggler.com/pdfs/ALLIGATOR%C2%AE-Solid-Wall-Anchors.pdf